# Why does my computer freeze and crash when I ask it to find the prime factorization of a very big number?

Tags: firefox, crash, primes, crash-reports, prime-factoring

This is a prime factorization calculator: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/arithmetic/numbers/prime-number/prime-factorization-calculator.php

When I enter a number in it, and then click on "Calculate", my computer will try to divide it by every prime number (up to its square root) to get its prime factorization.

But my question concerns what happens when I input a very big number...

Mozilla Firefox freezes and then crashes miserably.

But why? What was my computer thinking? Couldn't it realize that the number is too big and that there's no way he will succeed? And therefore why couldn't it just stop calculating instead of freezing and then crashing?

If I ask you to jump out of a window, you will evaluate the situation first, and then you will tel me: "no I won't, the height is too big". Likewise, when I ask my computer to calculate the prime factorization of a ridiculously big number, why can't it tell me: "no I won't, the number is too big"?

My computer just blindly calculates, never once hesitating, never once retreating, until it crashes into the big brick wall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes because of a bug in the page software

Actually, the page does try to detect this condition. If you look at the source it says

mw_translateObject['large1'] = "This is a very large number. The calculator may or may not be able to break it down before timing out."

If you enter a very large number and it crashes instead of displaying this message then it is a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Computers only do exactly what they are told. They don't step back and evaluate "hey is this a good idea?". If the "Calculate" function tries its hardest to find a factor, then it will keep doing that until it either succeeds or something goes wrong.

To make an evaluation about whether the input is "too big", the original programmer would have to write something specifically to decide what exactly "too big" means (it would be different for your desktop computer than your mobile phone), and not proceed if the number exceeds that. It may also be difficult to determine what "too big" actually means for a complex algorithm.

Comment: IOW our common execution model is incredibly poor, still, after 70+ years of computing history (it's just calculation). But it could have conceivably include execution in a sandbox for each new task, with all kinds of feedback like time elapsed, and projected time to completion (automatically derived) - as part of an execution model, w/out any intervention or a pre-thought of a programmer. Our compilers could always continually run in the background, trying to improve the running code, re-compiling and hot-swapping as needed. Then the *human* operator could intervene, having waited too long...

Comment: ... but that means having (possibly very high-level) source code available everywhere, and eventually, code-writing AI expert systems replacing human programmers, leaving place only for *designers*. So it's not coming our way *tomorrow* quite yet...

Comment: @WillNess: One might say that the execution model we currently have is terrible, but it's better than all the alternatives. :)